# How do I return a specific lambda if multiple of the same type are present? (KOTLIN)

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide

When I have for example two forEach lambdas, I'd like to return out of a specific one, for example thing1 in the following example, but not thing0.
If I try the following it'll complain that "There is more than one label with such a name in this scope"

Psuedo code to explain my issue:

```
thing0.forEach { _ ->
    thing1.forEach { _ ->
        // I'd like to return the thing1 forEach lambda, but the compiler
        // issues a warning that there are multiple forEach lambdas present.
        if (condition) return@forEach
    }
}
```

Comment: This page may be able to help? It gives all variants of labelled return there. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Comment: Cheers, mate! That did it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Cheers to Nick Lee for pointing me in the right direction!
Turns out I can just do the following:

```
thing0.forEach { _ ->
    thing1.forEach nameHere@{ _ ->
        // I'd like to return the thing1 forEach lambda, but the compiler
        // issues a warning that there are multiple forEach lambdas present.
        if (condition) return@nameHere
    }
}
```